# What causes crash in WSHStringToAddress() with a Widows Qt?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, crash, qtcpsocket

We are using `QTcpServer` and `QSslSocket` for server-client communication. Witnessing a crash once in a while in *one particular Windows machine*. Unfortunately in this machine, we don't have a debugger. Hence I could get the stack frame only with the "Process Explorer" utility from Windows. Here is the image:

[image]

Documentation for [WSHStringToAddress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/hardware/network/ff566028(v=vs.85)) function suggests that it's obsolete. This crash is not seen elsewhere.

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

After debugging we found out that,  `WSHStringToAddress()` is not a troublemaker, though obsolete. It's seen in the healthy app running as well as a "thread".

The root cause was within our code where there was an infinite recursion. Somehow, due to lack of stack frames, it was not seen properly with the above MS tool.